# Display names associated with colors in a palette instead of hex codes

Tags: r

I've a palette of colors (`my_pal`) that I need to use very often. To interact with this palette, I've adapted `my_color_pal` from [here](https://github.com/danielmarcelino/SciencesPo/blob/master/R/Palettes.R) It does work, but sometimes I want to be able to display the names in my palette instead of the hex color codes. Is it possible?

```
my_pal <- {
  x$y <- list()
  x$y$seasons <- c(
    autumn = rgb(100, 78, 139, max = 255),
    spring = rgb(200, 139, 61, max = 255),
    summer = rgb(54, 50, 205, max = 255),
    winter = rgb(255, 193, 37, max = 255)
  )
  x
}


my_color_pal <- function(palette = "seasons") {
  pal.list <- my_pal$y
  if (!palette %in% c(names(pal.list), "seasons", "blah", "bluh")) {
    stop(sprintf("%s is not a valid palette name", palette))
  }
  if (palette == "seasons") {
    types <- pal.list[["seasons"]][seq(1, 4, by = 1)]
  } else if (palette == "blah") {
    types <- pal.list[["blah"]][seq(1, 8, by = 2)]
  } else {
    types <- pal.list[[palette]]
  }
  function(n) {
    unname(types)[seq_len(n)]
  }
}


library(scales)
show_col(my_color_pal("seasons")(4))
```

[image]

Comment: The number of rgb colors vastly exceeds the number of named colors. I guess you can pick from a named vector if you know there is a limited number of options, but the code above doesn't actually set up a reproducible situation nor is the desired result at all clear.

Comment: @42- Sure, maybe I didn't make it clear, I'm interested in the names of seasons in this case. I'll aways deal with limited number of colors/factors that I can name it. The answer provided below by pete-barwis get close, though I wouldn't like to have to give a number in that function. Ideally, it should be smart enough to figure out how many factor do I have.

Comment: You got one answer, but I cannot tell if it was tested. I did paste the code to my console  but it unsurprisingly coughed out an error fro missing "x", and things did not go well from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you store the season names and the hex codes in your function, then you can retrieve the type you want to show when you build the plot. Here's an example that includes most of the internals of scales::show_col in your my_color_pal function, and then allows you to plot names or hex codes using a string value of "hex" or "names".

```
my_pal <- {
  x <- list()
  x$y <- list()
  x$y$seasons <- c(
    autumn = rgb(100, 78, 139, max = 255),
    spring = rgb(200, 139, 61, max = 255),
    summer = rgb(54, 50, 205, max = 255),
    winter = rgb(255, 193, 37, max = 255)
  )
  x
}


my_color_pal <- function(palette, names_or_hex) {

  pal.list <- my_pal$y
  if (!palette %in% c(names(pal.list), "seasons", "blah", "bluh")) {
    stop(sprintf("%s is not a valid palette name", palette))
  }
  if (palette == "seasons") {
    types <- pal.list[["seasons"]][seq(1, 4, by = 1)]
  } else if (palette == "blah") {
    types <- pal.list[["blah"]][seq(1, 8, by = 2)]
  } else {
    types <- pal.list[[palette]]
  }

  # get hexs
  colours <- unname(types)[seq_len(length(types))]

  # get names
  names_colours <- names(types)[seq_len(length(types))]

  # functions internal to scales::show_col()
  n <- length(colours)
  ncol <- ceiling(sqrt(n))
  nrow <- ceiling(n/ncol)
  colours <- c(colours, rep(NA, nrow * ncol - length(colours)))
  colours <- matrix(colours, ncol = ncol, byrow = TRUE)
  old <- par(pty = "s", mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0))
  on.exit(par(old))
  size <- max(dim(colours))
  plot(c(0, size), c(0, -size), type = "n", xlab = "", ylab = "", 
       axes = FALSE)
  rect(col(colours) - 1, -row(colours) + 1, col(colours), -row(colours), 
       col = colours)

  # add condtional plotting of hex codes or names
  if (names_or_hex == "hex") {
    text(col(colours) - 0.5, -row(colours) + 0.5, colours)
  } else if(names_or_hex == "names"){
    text(col(colours) - 0.5, -row(colours) + 0.5, names_colours)
  }

}

# plot and display hex codes
my_color_pal(palette = "seasons",
             names_or_hex = "hex")

# plot and display names
my_color_pal(palette = "seasons",
             names_or_hex = "names")
```

Comment: Thanks for the throughly work around; this really gets close, but I wouldn't like to have to pass a integer for the number of colors to be returned. I guess the function should be smart enough to figure out how many factor do I have in the list if I didn't supply a specific number, don't you agree?

Comment: I've edited the function to no longer need an integer value for n. I had been following your lead by passing the value explicitly in the arguments for show_col(my_color_pal("seasons")(4)). I, too, needed to add an empty list for x in order for your example to work. I hope this gets you what you need.